# How to access TypeResolutionContext in jackson 2.8.1

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am upgrading jackson library in a java project from version 2.4.6 to the latest version (2.8.1).
The following AnnotatedField constructor requires now a new parameter of type TypeResolutionContext

```
// v2.4.6
AnnotatedField(Field field, AnnotationMap annMap)

// v2.8.1
AnnotatedField(TypeResolutionContext contextClass, Field field, AnnotationMap annMap)
```

I read the API (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/TypeResolutionContext.html) but can't find how to get this TypeResolutionContext.

Only 2 classes implement this TypeResolutionContext (AnnotatedClass and TypeResolutionContext.Basic) but none of them seem to have suitable accessor methods that return a TypeResolutionContext.

Anyone knows how can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AnnotatedField` constructor, although public, should not be used directly -- it was not designed to be instantiated. So, the `TypeResolutionContext` parameter will in most cases work just fine if it is empty implemented, like this:

```
// lambda use to be more explicit (could be just null)
AnnotatedField annotatedField = new AnnotatedField( ( Type t) -> { return null; }, field, annMap);
```

(+ info a bit out of topic: `PropertyNamingStrategy` is also not supposed to be used outside of jackson project.)

source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-user/96wemvuUCHs